# Ignore input if it has no value

Tags: javascript

I've made a very simple calculator, i'm sure there is a better way of writing it, using JS to calculate the amount of rolls of wallpaper required. You have wall length, wall height, roll width, roll length and pattern repeat. My calculator works apart from when the pattern repeat is blank or 0 - 
So i need to ignore the value of input name="number3" (e)from my calculation if it is 0 - but not quite sure how to do this. Can i do it this with how I currently have written it or do i need to set the calculation differently?

```
function multiplymetric(){
    var a=Number(document.metriccalculator.number1a.value);
    var b=Number(document.metriccalculator.number1b.value);
    var c=Number(document.metriccalculator.number2a.value);
    var d=Number(document.metriccalculator.number2b.value);
    var e=Number(document.metriccalculator.number3.value);
    var f=Math.ceil(a/c);
    var g=Math.ceil(b/e);
    var h=Math.floor(d/(e*g));
    var i=Math.ceil(f/h);
    document.metriccalculator.total.value=i;
}

<form name="metriccalculator"> 
<input type="text" size="10" height="15" name="number1a">
<input type="text" size="10" height="15" name="number1b">
<input type="text" size="10" height="15" name="number2a">
<input type="text" size="10" height="15" name="number2b">
<input type="text" size="10" height="15" name="number3">
<input type="button" id="calcbutton" onclick="javascript:multiplymetric();" value="Calculate number of rolls">
<input type="text" size="10" height="15" name="total">
```

Comment: Seriously? One single long line? Who's supposed to read that?

Comment: add html and format the code

Comment: Test if the value is zero and initialize it with 1.

Comment: @deceze- Agreed, but give him a minute to fix it up. New user, posted on minute ago

Comment: @Dave Pile - cheers for the support man :) i'll tidy it up now
I didn't mean to post it as all one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute the instruction:

```
var g=Math.ceil(b/e);
```

with:

```
var g=Math.ceil(b/(e===0?1:e));
```

Comment: returns 0 total value